# Changing Android versionCode causes build.gradle error

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I just upgraded my Android Studio to 1.4.1.

In `build.gradle`, When i change my `versionCode`,

`import org.apache.commons.lang3.JavaVersion`

gets added to the top of `build.gradle`, which causes the error:

```
build file '/../app/build.gradle': 1: unable to resolve class org.apache.commons.lang3.JavaVersion
 @ line 1, column 1.
   import org.apache.commons.lang3.JavaVersion
```

When I remove the line `import org.apache.commons.lang3.JavaVersion`, it gets added back automatically after a while.

When I revert the versionCode back to 1, the import statement disappears and all is well.

**Gradle File**

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.JavaVersion

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.x.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0.1"
        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}
```

How do i solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Post how you have declared the `versionCode` in build.gradle file

Comment: Remove the import org.apache.commons.lang3.JavaVersion

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the import.

Your versionCode line in build.gradle should look like this :

`versionCode 3`

Comment: I removed the import statement it but it gets added back automatically.
http://pastebin.com/rLictGGg

Answer (score 0):

You use this class on compileOptions. That has nothing to do with pour versionCode, which is just fine.

Java 8 is not supported in Android, so I guess your problem is here